# NFS fileserver / computer clock not in sync despite NTP setup

Tags: nas, nfs, ntp

I have a fileserver running at home (Synology DS214se) which, among other things, serves my `/home/<user>` (per `pam_mount` controlled NFS).

This works just fine for all practical purposes, with one exception: The timestamps on my computer and the fileserver are not completely in sync.

This has no practical impact, except for when I `make` software. Every now and then, `make` will give me warnings about "something wrong with the clock", and files having timestamps zero-point-something seconds into the future.

Both my computer and the fileserver are configured to use my router (FritzBox) as NTP server.

**Are these kind of sub-second drifts to be expected with NTP? Is there anything I can do about it?**

The OS on my computer is Linux Mint 17. The fileserver runs Synology's own DSM 5.2.

---

```
$ ntpq -pcrv
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*fritz.box       147.231.100.5    3 u   21   64   17    1.748   -0.978   0.509
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Thu Jan 21 23:29:25 UTC 2016 (1)",
processor="i686", system="Linux/3.13.0-24-generic", leap=00, stratum=4,
precision=-19, rootdelay=50.485, rootdisp=969.755, refid=192.168.178.1,
reftime=da66a126.0e8a0d9f  Thu, Feb 11 2016  6:56:54.056,
clock=da66a13b.58385082  Thu, Feb 11 2016  6:57:15.344, peer=33542, tc=6,
mintc=3, offset=-0.978, frequency=0.209, sys_jitter=0.000,
clk_jitter=0.346, clk_wander=0.066
```

Comment: From your linux box can you do `ntpq -pcrv` and post the result in your question please.

Comment: @user3788685: Added.

Comment: Those stats look ok at a glance, but I see some rather big numbers for things like `rootdisp=969.755` & `rootdelay=50.485` which don't look good. How many external NTP servers is your fritz.box looking at?

Comment: @user3788685: Only one, 0.europe.pool.ntp.org. I'm pretty noob when it comes to NTP; I don't even know what those numbers mean or what would be "large" for any of them. :-\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTP behaves best when it has at least 3 servers to pick from, ideally 5. The short answer to your question is 'no' well behaved timing systems should be within a few ms of the reference source.

As to what the numbers mean - have a look [here](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/NTPRelatedDefinitions) at the NTP definitions it explains what things like `rootdelay` & `rootdisp` mean and is probably a good place to start.

Here is what I suggest you try to see if you can improve your timing;

Don't use the FritzBox as a time server - routers are generally very bad at this task.

Don't use the NAS box as a time server - I have a few of these Synology units on sites all over and they are *all* really bad at keeping time as clients or servers. (mine all run with an offset of at least +1.5)

If you have a stable (linux) PC that's on 24/7 that would be a better choice if you want to run your own timing system, but you don't need to do that.

Configure your FritzBox to use 1 manually selected server which is a good ping to your network.

Configure your PC to use the same single internet server.

Configure the NAS Box to use the same internet server. - If you go into the command line/ssh you can tweak the config file for ntp if you need to.

If you use the same single source for everything it should minimise your issue in this case.